# creating multiple shapes closer -illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

If I creating a new shape closer to the another shape,the cursor was changed to **transform icon** for the older shape. so that each and every time I press **"v"** and click on empty surface and again choose the shape tool to draw a shape.

*How can I solve this??*

Comment: YOur making lines and you want to disable shape widgets?

Answer (score 1):

Make a shape, then press Command+Shift+A (Mac) or Ctrl+Shift+A (Windows).

You may also create and use a simpler shortcut:
Click Edit/Keyboard Shortcuts..., click "Tools" and choose "Menu Commands".
Choose Select/Deselect. Click the Command+Shift+A shortcut.
Press a function key You'll use instead of Command+Shift+A.
Click OK. Click OK again to save the changes to Your set of shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

When you draw a shape it remains selected. It could be that the Bounding Box is getting in your way. The Bounding Box allows you to resize, stretch, or rotate selected objects.

Try going to View> Hide Bounding Box.

If you really want to keep the Bounding Box active on your shapes then deselecting your shape before you try making another shape will help. The previous answer gives a way to deselect. I find the fastest way is to hold the command/ctrl key down- this temporarily changes the tool you are using to your last used selection tool (white arrow or black arrow). Then just click on an empty section of your artboard (or even off the artboard) to deselect your shape, release the command/ ctrl key, and carry on drawing your shapes.